# How to run specs after Sinatra app reloads using Guard?

Tags: rspec, sinatra, capybara, rack, guard

Using guard-rack to reload the app. It reloads the app properly, but how to run the specs after it reloads?

```
guard :rack do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})

  callback(:reload) { `rspec spec` }
end
```

The callback is supposed to run the specs after the app is updated, but nothing seems to happen.

Config:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :poltergeist
  config.app_host = 'http://localhost:9292'
end
```

Also using guard-rspec:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'rspec spec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/(.+)\.rb$}) { 'spec' }
end
```

Reference : [Guard Docs](https://github.com/guard/guard#callback)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Anthony, I figured it out. The rspec guard has to ***come after*** the rack guard:

```
guard :rack do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})
end

guard :rspec, cmd: 'rspec spec' do
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})  { 'spec' }
  watch(%r{^spec/(.+)\.rb$}) { 'spec' }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

We use [gaurd-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) at work, it's great.  Config is as simple as:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'rspec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
end
```

Comment: Actually I am using guard-rspec as well. But I am running Sinatra outside of RSpec.